# Automatically populate id field with _id string

Tags: mongodb

I'm attempting to map an object with an unpopulated 'id' field into MongoDB and to have that 'id' field populated with the string value of the autopoplated '_id' field.  I'd like to use the string from the ObjectID '_id' field generated by MongoDB for uniqueness and the timestamp property of BSON objects.  However, I've been unable to find a simple way to make MongoDB handle this.  Below are the solutions that I've found thus far, but I was hoping someone could tell me a better way of doing this.

1) Insert object into database, then use the $addFields operator to add an 'id' field based on the string of the '_id' field.  This seems clumsy as requires 2 database operations (insert then update) for inserting a single document.

2) Create a new ObjectID and set this as the '_id' field and the string from this as the 'id' field before inserting the object into the database.  That is what I'm currently doing as it only requires a single insert operation, but it not ideal when doing a bulk insert via insertMany().

The idea solution would be to either have mongodb automatically populate an 'id' field on document insertion, similar to option #1 but without requiring multiple database operations.  Thanks for the help.

Comment: If i understood your point right, $setOnInsert is what you are looking for.
==>var objId = new ObjectId() <==
|| ==>>db.coll1.update({_id:objId},{$setOnInsert:{'id':objId}},{upsert:true}) <==
Sorry for formatting in comments

Comment: @Avij thanks for the help.  Your usage of $setOnInsert looks close to what I want, but not quite what I'm after.  You're still generating a new ObjectId before inserting the object into the database, and so I could just as easily update my object before inserting into the database as I described in my solution #2 as this seems to be equally as efficient as using $setOnInsert as you've described.  If, however, I could get the ObjectId that is created by Mongo upon object insertion and use $setOnInsert to set 'id' to the string value of that new ObjectId in a single update call then I'd be set.